# Execute middleware on every route call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

In my Express application I implement routes in routes.ts:

```js
    var Router = express.Router();

    Router.route('/models/:modelId')
      .get(function (req, res) {
          service.setParameter(req)
          service.get(req,res)
    });
 
     Router.route('/models/:modelId')
      .post(function (req, res) {
          service.setParameter(req)
          service.post(req,res)
    });
```

And express.ts:

```js
    export const App = express()

    App.use(express.json())
    App.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    App.use(helmet())

    App.use('/', Router)
```

At each router call I'd like to execute a piece of code service.setParameter(req) that gets particular parameter from 'params', but I don't want to add to each router method explicitly.

I tried adding it at as middleware before and after Router

```js
    App.use('/', Router)

    App.use(function(req, res, next){
      service.setParameter(req)
      next()
    })
```

But if I define it before Router then route hasn't been set yet, and I don't get the parameter I want, and if I define it after, then middleware is not executed.

How can execute service.setParameter(req) in a generic way so that it applies to all the routes?

Answer (score 2):

In `express.ts` file, you can add a middleware that would do it before mounding the Router, and then just procced forward with `next()`. You can do it like this:

```js
App.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  service.setParameter(req);
  next();
});

App.use('/', Router)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your custom middleware between the context path and your router inside `app.use(..)`:

```
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    service.post(req,res);
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    service.get(req,res)
});

app.use('/models', (req, res, next) => {
    service.setParameter(req);
    next();
}, router);
```

With above code the middleware will be excecuted for all requests to `'/models'`.

Comment: Thanks @eol. Is req.params expected to be available in middleware? It comes up as 'undefined' for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for `req.params` and not for `req.query`? `req.params` represent the path-params and not the params you pass in as a query string. If you're trying to match path-params you need to specify them in your context-path, e.g. `app.use('/models/:someId', ...)`

Comment: Yeah, it's path parameters that I am looking for. I updated my OP to reflect my structure - Router being in a different file, perhaps this is cause of the issue because there is disconnect between App and Router, where Router cannot get reference to the App.

Comment: Ok, and have you tried my solution from the comment, i.e. `app.use('/models/:modelId', ...)`?

Comment: Yes, This is what I did https://pastebin.com/bhDbDUYN, but I am getting 404 when I execute that endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.use(async (req,res,next) => {...})` in order to declare a middleware that executes in all the requests, if you want this middleware to be called first, it must be declare before than your routes, the middleware have to call `next()`  in order to continue with the execution flow, if you want to be called at the end of you request, you have to put at the end of your declarations but before of the error middleware, in that approach each route have to call `next()` at the end of your function.

**First approach**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    await service.post(req,res);
});

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await service.get(req,res)
});

app.use((req,res,next) => {
   console.log("always called");
   next();
});
app.use('/',router);
```

**Second approach**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    await service.post(req,res);
    next();
});

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    await service.get(req,res);
    next();
});

app.use('/',router);
app.use((req,res) => {
   console.log("always called");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, they helped me better understand how routing works on Express.

I found another solution, which I think works best in my case - using Router.all() method:

```
const setRequest = function(req, res, next){
  logger.setRequest(request)
  next()
}

Router.route('/models/:model_id')
.all(setRequest)
.get(function (req, res) {service.execute()})
.put(function (req, res) {service.execute()})
```